# onActivityResult not working in Intent.Action.Send

Tags: android, android-intent, onactivityresult

I am using Intent.Action.Send for Send data like(image,text).I want Result Data Send or not but onActivityResult is not working.Please check the code .help me .
Get Error:-

```
 01-25 19:12:49.160 140-19149/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]
 01-25 19:12:49.160 140-19149/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: checkDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]
 01-25 19:12:49.161 140-19149/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: checkDcf: not  dcf type, dcf version value [80]
 01-25 19:12:49.164 139-139/? E/DrmMtkUtil/DrmUtil: parseDcf: not dcf type, dcf version value [80]
 01-25 19:12:49.164 139-139/? E/DrmMtkPlugIn: onOpenDecryptSession() : failed to parse dcf file.
 01-25 19:12:49.192 140-19149/? E/AsfParser: unknown object: 20000000-7466-7079-4d34412000000000, 541144141 bytes
 01-25 19:12:49.192 140-19149/? E/AsfParser: error parsing header: -6
 01-25 19:12:49.198 140-27751/? E/MtkOmxAudioDecBase: MtkOmxAudioDecBase:SetParameter unsupported nParamIndex(0x7F00001E)
 01-25 19:12:49.200 140-27751/? E/OMXCodec: @@ [OUT] def.nBufferSize = 24576
 01-25 19:12:49.200 140-27751/? E/OMXCodec: @@ [OUT] totalSize = 221696
 01-25 19:12:49.201 27103-27103/? E/MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
  01-25 19:12:49.203 140-16861/? E/OMXCodec: [OMX.MTK.AUDIO.DECODER.AAC] +waitForBufferFilled_l: 4/0
   01-25 19:12:49.204 140-27754/? E/OMXCodec: @@ [OUT] def.nBufferSize = 24576
01-25 19:12:49.204 140-27754/? E/OMXCodec: @@ [OUT] totalSize = 221696
 01-25 19:12:49.205 140-16861/? E/OMXCodec: [OMX.MTK.AUDIO.DECODER.AAC] -waitForBufferFilled_l
 01-25 19:12:49.205 140-16861/? E/OMXCodec: [OMX.MTK.AUDIO.DECODER.AAC] +waitForBufferFilled_l: 6/0
 01-25 19:12:49.206 140-16861/? E/OMXCodec: [OMX.MTK.AUDIO.DECODER.AAC] -waitForBufferFilled_l
01-25 19:12:49.208 140-27755/? E/OMXCodec: [OMX.MTK.AUDIO.DECODER.AAC] No more output data in fillOutputBuffer, mFilledBuffers size=3
01-25 19:12:49.208 140-27755/? E/OMXCodec: [OMX.MTK.AUDIO.DECODER.AAC] No more output data in fillOutputBuffer, mFilledBuffers size=2
01-25 19:12:49.208 140-27755/? E/OMXCodec: [OMX.MTK.AUDIO.DECODER.AAC] No more output data in fillOutputBuffer, mFilledBuffers size=1
01-25 19:12:49.208 140-27755/? E/OMXCodec: [OMX.MTK.AUDIO.DECODER.AAC] No more output data in fillOutputBuffer, mFilledBuffers size=0
 01-25 19:12:49.208 140-27755/? E/OMXCodec: [OMX.MTK.AUDIO.DECODER.AAC] read() final return
```

[image]

[image]

Adapter Class:-

```
 holder.shareRL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String des = eventlist.get(position).get("Description");
            String location = eventlist.get(position).get("location");
            String time = eventlist.get(position).get("Event_date_time");
            String title = eventlist.get(position).get("Event_title");

            intent_str = "Event Show " + "\n " + title + " \n" + time + "\n" + location + "\n" + des;

            TredingFragment.Share_intent((Activity) mContext);
    }
```

TredingFragment class :-

```
public static void Share_intent(Activity activity) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Eventlist_adapter.intent_str);
        //activity.setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);      
        activity.startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share and earn a extra Priviledge"), 111);

    }
```

onActivityResult

```
   @Override
       public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        //  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        Log.e("code", REQUEST_FOR_ACTIVITY_CODE + "");
        Log.e("result", requestCode + "");
        Log.e("result", resultCode + "");
        if (requestCode == 111) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Log.e("result", "okkkk" + "");
               // Toast.makeText(this, "Ok DUDE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
              // Toast.makeText(this, "Oversmart Eh!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.e("result", "okkk" + "");
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Where is your `onActivityResult` defined? When calling `activity.startActivityForResult` from fragment result will still be delivered to `activity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ACTION_SEND` does not return a result ("Output: nothing" in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND)), and so it is pointless to use it with `startActivityForResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

App which is opened through `ACTION_SEND` intent does not close by itself unless the user presses `Back` button. So there is not use of waiting for result from that `Intent`.